# Unit test ASP.NET Core routing & endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I just fixed a bug that was caused by bad endpoint routing.  I'd like to create an E2E unit test that would verify that the routing (and other server stats) are OK.  So, my question is: What is the best way to get a text description of the server routing?  For example, generate `endpointDesc` like:

```cs
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

        var es = endpoints.DataSources                    
            .SelectMany(d => d.Endpoints.Select(e => e.ToString()));
        var endpointDesc = String.Join("\n",es);
        DBG.Log(endpointDesc);
    });
```

but more useful (& not calculated in UseEndpoints()).

Comment: that would require testing framework code. I would suggest an integration test to the endpoint to verify endpoiints.

Comment: @Nikosi Yes, I'm thinking of an E2E test that makes a REST call to get server stats..or even a HealthCheck.

Comment: Also, my bug had to do with the config/interaction with endpoints. So I'm looking for "system-level" tests rather than "unit-level" tests of individual endpoints.